# MAUI control template with multiple content presenters - the content no longer has access to page's binding context

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I had a `CardView` control with one `<ContentPresenter />` that looked like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Eaton.Mdm.Resources.Controls"
             x:Class="Eaton.Mdm.Resources.Controls.CardView">
    <ContentView.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="CardViewControlTemplate">
            <Border Stroke="Gray"
                    StrokeThickness="1">
                <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,*">
                    <Grid Grid.Row="0"
                          BackgroundColor="{TemplateBinding HeaderBackgroundColor}">
                        <VerticalStackLayout Margin="{StaticResource ContentMargin}">
                            <Label x:Name="TitleLabel" 
                                   Text="{TemplateBinding Title}"
                                   TextColor="{TemplateBinding HeaderTextColor}"
                                   FontSize="{StaticResource Heading5Size}" />
                            <Label x:Name="SubtitleLabel" 
                                   Text="{TemplateBinding Subtitle}"
                                   TextColor="{TemplateBinding HeaderTextColor}"
                                   FontSize="{StaticResource Subtitle1Size}" />
                        </VerticalStackLayout>
                    </Grid>

                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" Margin="{StaticResource ContentMargin}" />
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>

        <Style TargetType="local:CardView">
            <Setter Property="ControlTemplate"
                    Value="{StaticResource CardViewControlTemplate}" />
        </Style>
    </ContentView.Resources>
</ContentView>
```

When using it within another page, the bindings would work flawlessly:

```xml
<!-- MyPage.xaml -->
<Grid RowDefinitions="*,Auto" Margin="{StaticResource PageMargin}">
  <controls:CardView Grid.Row="0" 
                  Title="{Binding MyTitle}" 
                  Subtitle="{Binding MySubtitle}"
                  HeaderTextColor="White"
                  HeaderBackgroundColor="{StaticResource Primary}"
                  HeightRequest="{StaticResource OverviewCardHeight}"
                  VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
      <Label Text="{Binding SomeText}" />
  </controls:CardView>
```

Due to the need to add some skeleton animations for title and subtitle in some instances, I had to change my `CardView` to look like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Eaton.Mdm.Resources.Controls"
             x:Class="Eaton.Mdm.Resources.Controls.CardView">
    <ContentView.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="CardViewControlTemplate">
            <Border Stroke="Gray"
                    StrokeThickness="1"
                    BindingContext="{Binding Source={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,*">
                    <Grid Grid.Row="0"
                          BackgroundColor="{TemplateBinding HeaderBackgroundColor}">
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"/>
                    </Grid>

                    <ContentPresenter 
                        Grid.Row="1" 
                        Margin="{StaticResource ContentMargin}"
                        Content="{TemplateBinding Body}"/>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>

        <Style TargetType="local:CardView">
            <Setter Property="ControlTemplate"
                    Value="{StaticResource CardViewControlTemplate}" />
        </Style>
    </ContentView.Resources>
</ContentView>
```

Here's the code-behind for that:

```cs
public partial class CardView : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty HeaderBackgroundColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(HeaderBackgroundColor), typeof(Color), typeof(CardView), Colors.White);
    public static readonly BindableProperty HeaderProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Header), typeof(IView), typeof(CardView));
    public static readonly BindableProperty BodyProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Body), typeof(IView), typeof(CardView));

    public Color HeaderBackgroundColor
    {
        get => (Color)GetValue(HeaderBackgroundColorProperty);
        set => SetValue(HeaderBackgroundColorProperty, value);
    }

    public IView Header
    {
        get => (IView)GetValue(HeaderProperty);
        set => SetValue(HeaderProperty, value);
    }

    public IView Body
    {
        get => (IView)GetValue(BodyProperty);
        set => SetValue(BodyProperty, value);
    }

    public CardView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Now using it within another page would look something like this:

```xml
<!-- MyPage.xaml -->

<controls:CardView Grid.Row="0"
                    HeaderBackgroundColor="{StaticResource Primary}"
                    HeightRequest="{StaticResource OverviewCardHeight}"
                    VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
  <controls:CardView.Header>
    <VerticalStackLayout>
      <Label Text="{Binding MyTitle}" />
      <Label Text="{Binding MySubtitle}" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
  </controls:CardView.Header>

  <controls:CardView.Body>
    <Label Text="{Binding MyBody}" />
  </controls:CardView.Body>
</controls:CardView>
```

Here the bindings within the body or header (*e.g.* `MyBody`, `MyTitle`, `MySubtitle`) no longer work. I have found a workaround for this, but I am not a big fan of:

```xml
"{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MyPageViewModel}}, Path=MyBody}"
```

Why does this happen and what changes to make to the `CardView` control so that the content uses the binding context of the page it's part of?

Comment: From your code, I found that you have put the binded property into the inner element of your customView, so you cannot bind value to it as the former method.

Comment: Hi, could you please detail a bit in a full answer? Why is it not possible? What alternative do I have? Clearly there's layout controls such as `Grid` which do accept multiple contents, do work with binding directly to the containing page's binding context and do achieve something similar to what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Just as you said, you can use  [Relative Bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/relative-bindings) to achieve this.